# Django: Pass filter to custom QuerySet

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to pass `_filter` to the QuerySet Manager as I try here? Currently, I always receive the error message `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

```
def get_super_guests(self):
    _filter = "answers__choices__answer='Very disappointed', answer_NPS__gte=9"
    return Response.objects.get_super_guests(self.request.event.pk, _filter)


class ResponseQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def get_super_guests(self, event_pk, _filter):
        return (
            self.filter(
                survey__event=event_pk,
                survey__template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT,
                answers__question__focus__in=[
                    QuestionFocus.FEELING_ABOUT_ATTENDING_AGAIN,
                    QuestionFocus.RECOMMENDATION_TO_FRIENDS,
                ],
            )
            .annotate(
                answer_NPS=Case(
                    When(
                        answers__question__focus=QuestionFocus.RECOMMENDATION_TO_FRIENDS,
                        then=Cast(
                            'answers__answer', output_field=IntegerField()
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            .filter(
                _filter
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I just figured out a better way. Works perfectly :)

```
def get_super_guests(self):
    return Response.objects.get_super_guests(self.request.event.pk).filter(
        answers__choices__answer="Very disappointed",
        answer_NPS__gte=9,
    )
```